# Java: Javascript-like split behavior

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a javascript code like:

```
var tmp = "abcdefg";
alert(tmp.split(/(b)(c)/));
```

which gives me

```
[a,b,c,defg]
```

which is what i want, but when I did it in Java, it only splits the string removing the matching regex.

```
String tmp = "abcdefg";
tmp.split("(b)(c)"));
```

which gives me

```
[a,defg]
```

How can I make the split in Java behave like the split in javascript?

Comment: I'm trying figure out what version of regex works like your JavaScrip "example."

Comment: @markspace: That's the way JavaScript's `split` works with capture groups. All the gory details: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, so it's the `split()` method, not regex *per se.*  Weird, but I guess I learned something.

Comment: @markspace: Right. The question doesn't say it's a regex thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Java use lookahead based regex:

```
"abcdefg".split( "(?=[bc])|(?<=[bc])" );
```

**Code:**

```
String[] toks = "abcdefg".split( "(?=[bc])|(?<=[bc])" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("<%s>%n", tok);
```

#### Output:

```
<a>
<b>
<c>
<defg>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you can't keep capturing group in a regex split in Java, but you can write:

```
(?=bc)|(?<=b)(?=c)|(?<=bc)
```

Comment: It works, but i think the regex may get too complicated faster this way. Is there any workaround without altering the regex?

Comment: @user2773086: Well, you can always do the loop yourself with your original regex, since Java's split doesn't do what you want. Just loop, applying the regex, adding strings to a list, then do toArray at the end.